# Adding a key, value to a dict, but I didn't tell it to?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on some game code in python 3.7. I'm using a lot of dictionaries to store various data, and at one point I needed a new dictionary to store certain values from one dictionary as keys in other dictionaries. When I ran the code, I ended up with a value in my new dictionary that I can't figure out why it got in there.
Example:

```
data = {'value1': 4, 'value2': 'hello'}
target = {'value1': 3}

def fillTarget(info, times):
    for key, value in info.items():
        if key == 'value2':
            target[key] = value
            target[value] = times
        else:
            for _ in range(times):
                target[key] = target[key] + info[key]
            
fillTarget(data, 4)
```

When I print(target), I end up with:

```
{'value1': 19, 'value2': 'hello', 'hello': 4}
```

Why am I getting 'value2' as a key, value in (target)? Isn't line 6-8 telling it to add the value as a key, but then the else: should not transfer the key to (target)?

Comment: `target[key] = value` is inserting the value into the `target` dictionary.

Comment: Trace through the code.  When it gets to 'value2' / 'hello', you will set `target['value2'] = 'hello'`, and `target['hello'] = 4`.  Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Please re-read your questions and look at your code. Many of the questions you ask are answered by the code you wrote. Perhaps it would be better if you describe the behaviour you wanted to encode, rather than asking why your code is doing _exactly_ what you said it should do. Also I'm not sure what you even mean by your last question

Answer (score 0):

You are adding two items to dictionary

```c
target[key] = value //{'value2': 'hello'}
// and
target[value] = times //{'hello': 4 }
//where key = 'value2', value = 'hello' and times = 4
```

Click [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_dictionary_add_item.asp) to get more details on how to add items to dictionary in python.

Comment: I get it. I forget that in this instance "value" is treated like a variable. Thank you!